# How to authorize user owns resource using API through middleware in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I need to check if user is permitted to view resource. Request is sent by API and passes through `auth:api` middleware. I'm using Laravel 5.8

I tried to use middleware in route declaration like this:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', 'UserController@get')->middleware('can:view,user')
```

or in method's controller code like this:

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
$this->authorize('view', $user, $anotherUserModel);
```

Each of these methods either lets user pass policy even it's hardcoded to stops user form achieving this or throws error:

```
{
    "message": "This action is unauthorized.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravelapitest\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
    "line": 202,
    [...]
}
```

but I'm expecting that user should be stopped and response code should be 403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please give this a try and let me know if it fixes your problem.

Go to **App\Exceptions** folder and add the following at the top of the **Handler.php** file:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
```

add the following to **$dontReport** array in the same file:

```
\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
```

and the last step is to customize error response by adding the following code in the render function:

```
if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
    return response()->json('unauthorized',403);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, just like that you can handle any error exception and do whatever you want to do if it happens. learn more about error handling on laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors